# how to catch QUERY_STRING while using post method in SSI

Tags: post, ssi

This is my basic index.shtml,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<input name="fname" type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<!--#echo var="QUERY_STRING" -->
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to catch the `QUERY_STRING` but it prints nothing. As per SSI documentation I think this works for only GET method. Is there any way to catch the string while using POST method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When using POST, there _is_ no query string (unless the page that the form was on already contained one).

Comment: Is there any way to catch the data submitted using post in ssi?

Comment: Not that I know of. You might need to use another server-side technique – PHP, Perl, …